# Console application menu

Tags: java, design-patterns, state

Sometimes I need to write a simple Java console applications and menu look:

```
do {
    System.out.println("please select menu item");
    System.out.println("1-create, 2-remove, 3 - rename");
    int select;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    select = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (select) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("please select menu item");
            System.out.println("1-image, 2-txt");
            select = scanner.nextInt();
            if (select == 1) fileHolder.create("image");
            else if (select == 2) fileHolder.create("image");
            else System.out.println("invalid menu item");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("please select menu item");
            System.out.println("1-file from pc1, 2-file from pc2, 3-file from pc3");
            select = scanner.nextInt();
            if (select == 1) fileHolder.removeFile("pc1");
            else if (select == 2) fileHolder.removeFile("pc2");
            else if (select == 3) fileHolder.removeFile("pc3");
            else System.out.println("invalid menu item");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("please type new name");
            String newName = scanner.next();
            fileHolder.rename(newName);
            break;
    }

} while (select != 4);
```

But I believe that it is not the best choice. I believe that I should use any pattern to improve my code. By description - the state pattern is applicable for my situation but I have no idea how I can use this in this situation. The menu should show the respective menu according to the internal state.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there are at least three buggy things:

- `select` variable is declared inside the `do... while` loop, so the condition in `while` is checked against another one (probably, a field in the class?). So, the loop won't work as expected!
- *copy-paste is evil*. The calls `fileHolder.create("image");` are repeated in two different conditionals. The `"txt"` option is not used. Please pay more attention to the things you write and do not copy-paste such elementary things.
- the `Scanner` is not closed after its usage, which is desirable, as for any other items that use I/O.

For the rest, the code seems quite straightforward, rigid and repetitive, hence difficult to maintain. It contains many `if - else if` clauses that smell bad.

Of course, the whole story may be refactored with patterns usage. But I don't think that the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) suits well here. It'd be better refactored with the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

All the menu actions (*create*, *remove*, *rename* and their dependent ones) may be wrapped into separate objects, which associate the expected keys (1,2,3..), the text and other necessary stuff and sugar.

For example, a (very short) version of `Menu` class could be like this:

```
class Menu {

  private final String action;
  private final Consumer<String> consumer;

  Menu(String action, Consumer<String> consumer) {
    this.action = action;
    this.consumer = consumer;
  }

  void execute() {
    this.consumer.accept(action);
  }
}
```

And it would be initialized and used:

```
Menu create = new Menu("create", (a) -> fileHolder.create(a));
// to trigger the execution:
create.execute();
```

But for this very concrete and short example of code I would consider decomposing it into patterns as a sort of overkill.

There is some job to do about the original straightforward approach, so let's just try to improve it.

The input numbers are read several times using the `Scanner` object. They should also be validated, so a dedicated method would be very useful:

```
// int minValue may also be defined if necessary
private static int askUserForNumberInput(Scanner scanner, String prompt, int maxValue) {
  System.out.println("please select menu item");
  System.out.println(prompt);
  int value = scanner.nextInt();
  while (value < 1 || value > maxValue) {
    System.out.println("invalid menu item, please try again");
    // java.util.InputMismatchException should also be caught 
    // to intercept non-numeric input
    value = scanner.nextInt();
  }
  return value;
}
```

The frame for the main logic would look like this:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  final int mainMenuSelection = askUserForNumberInput(scanner, "1-create, 2-remove, 3 - rename", 3);
  switch (mainMenuSelection) {
    // cases
  }
}
```

And there is not a single `if - if else` in the cases any more:

```
case 1: {
  String[] createActions = { "image", "txt" }; // to be extracted to constants
  int createOption = askUserForNumberInput(scanner, "1-image, 2-txt", 2);
  fileHolder.create(createActions[createOption - 1]);
  break;
}
case 2: {
  int removeIndex = askUserForNumberInput(scanner, "1-file from pc1, 2-file from pc2, 3-file from pc3", 3);
  fileHolder.removeFile("pc" + removeIndex);
  break;
}
case 3: {
  System.out.println("please type new name");
  String newName = scanner.next();
  fileHolder.rename(newName);
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of repetition in your code which is always a sure sign that some methods or classes should be introduced.  It seems that you did understand that already.

I like your idea of using the state pattern.  I made an implementation below where the state (the active menu) is kept in the variable `menu` of `App`.  There can be a tree of sub-menus.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Menu {
    private final String name;
    private final String text;
    private LinkedHashMap<String, Runnable> actionsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Menu(String name, String text) {
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void putAction(String name, Runnable action) {
        actionsMap.put(name, action);
    }

    public String generateText() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(name).append(": ");
        sb.append(text).append(":\n");
        List<String> actionNames = new ArrayList<>(actionsMap.keySet());
        for (int i = 0; i < actionNames.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(String.format(" %d: %s%n", i + 1, actionNames.get(i)));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void executeAction(int actionNumber) {
        int effectiveActionNumber = actionNumber - 1;
        if (effectiveActionNumber < 0 || effectiveActionNumber >= actionsMap.size()) {
            System.out.println("Ignoring menu choice: " + actionNumber);
        } else {
            List<Runnable> actions = new ArrayList<>(actionsMap.values());
            actions.get(effectiveActionNumber).run();
        }
    }

    public static class App {
        private Menu menu;
        private String password = "blahblah";

        public App() {
            Menu mainMenu = new Menu("Main", "main menu");
            Menu subMenuGetPassword = new Menu("Password", "get passwords");
            Menu subMenuSetPassword = new Menu("Set Password", "set password");

            mainMenu.putAction("get password menu", () -> activateMenu(subMenuGetPassword));
            mainMenu.putAction("quit", () -> System.exit(0));

            subMenuGetPassword.putAction("get password", () -> System.out.println(password));
            subMenuGetPassword.putAction("set password menu", () -> activateMenu(subMenuSetPassword));
            subMenuGetPassword.putAction("main menu", () -> activateMenu(mainMenu));
            subMenuGetPassword.putAction("quit", () -> System.exit(0));

            subMenuSetPassword.putAction("get password", this::setPassword);
            subMenuSetPassword.putAction("step back menu", () -> activateMenu(subMenuGetPassword));
            subMenuSetPassword.putAction("main menu", () -> activateMenu(mainMenu));
            subMenuSetPassword.putAction("quit", () -> System.exit(0));

            activateMenu(mainMenu);            
        }

        private void activateMenu(Menu newMenu) {
            menu = newMenu;
            System.out.println(newMenu.generateText());
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (true) {
                // TODO some error checking.
                int actionNumber = scanner.nextInt();
                menu.executeAction(actionNumber);
            }
        }

        private void setPassword() {
            // TODO ask for password on command lin eand set it
            password = "p2";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }
}
```